# CSS Navigation Link Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I was wondering if there was any way to achieve this look for navigation hover with CSS? I've tried using a box-shadow effect, but the blur effect would bleed to the sides. As shown in the image, I really want the cut-off look along the edges as well as the gradient applied ONLY to the bottom edge.

[image: Navigation Hover Effect]

Also, this doesn't need to be achieved with CSS; JS or JQ is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/4tbsnsqd/) is a jsFiddle that should do what you're asking for.

Here's the code:

```css
body {
    background: #e8e8e8;
}

nav {
    background: #DEC8A0;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

nav:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: linear-gradient( 25deg, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #DEC8A0 50%, #DEC8A0 100% ),
                      linear-gradient( -25deg, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #DEC8A0 50%, #DEC8A0 100% );
    background-size: 28px 16px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -16px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    content: "";
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

nav a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 0px purple;
}

nav a:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient( purple, transparent );
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a>About</a>
    <a>Other</a>
</nav>
```

This is a bit intense, so I'll walk you through the various things we're doing:

To accomplish the interesting cutout border, we use gradients applied to the background of the `:before` pseudo-element of the `nav`. You can use any angles you want -- `-45` and `45` degrees will make really sharp zigzags, and anything below will do nice, gradual angles like we have in this example.

Then, to accomplish the hover effect: there are two components at work. To get the top part of the hover effect, I use an inset `box-shadow` that is the same color as the start of the gradient. Then, to get the gradient, I use the `:before` pseudo element of the `nav a`, which has a height greater than the link itself, and also a lower z-index than the `nav` element so it sits below.

Finally -- if you're not familiar with it, I'm using flexboxes to center the navigation text vertically.

This all adds up to the effect you're (hopefully) looking for!

**EDIT:** In case you have fluid width links, you just need to set the width of `nav a` to auto and add the desired padding on the ends:

```css
nav a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Keep in mind that when doing this, you need to set `left: 0` on the `:before` pseudo-element since we need it to stick to the left of the link:

```css
nav a:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient( purple, transparent );
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/4tbsnsqd/1/) is an updated fiddle with all of this added in.

Comment: This is almost perfect!! But is there any way to adjust the proportions of nav a using padding instead of width and height? It's just because my navigation links have varied lengths, which makes it look awkward when limited to a fixed width.

Comment: THANK YOU!! Perfect answer, and thank you for the in-depth explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/czg2god8/)

I assume that your `HTML` looks like that. What you need is to make a `link` displayed as `inline-block` (so you can set the `width` and `height` of the `link`), set the `line-height` the same with the `navigation bar height`, then set the `height` of the `link` to some number higher than the `navigation bar height`, then use `CSS hover` to make the `link` have some `background-color` from some color to transparent

***Note**: this will have some browser compatibility issue because some older browser doesn't support `CSS3 Gradients`

```css
body {
    background: blue;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    background: #919924;
}
a {
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 125px;
}
a:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, transparent);
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, transparent);
    /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, transparent);
    /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(red, transparent);
    /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#">
        My Cats
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        My Dogs
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        My Pets
    </a>
</nav>
```

### EDIT:

If you want the gradient to apply on the bottom edge, then you can change the `CSS` by adding `a:after` for the `gradient effect` like this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/czg2god8/1/)

you need to make the `link` to `position: relative`, then create a `a:after` with `position: absolute` and `z-index: -1`

***Note**: For `:after` to work, you need to add `content: ''` or else it won't be created

```css
body {
    background: blue;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    background: #919924;
}
a {
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: -1;
}
a:hover:after {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, transparent);
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, transparent);
    /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, transparent);
    /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(red, transparent);
    /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#">
        My Cats
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        My Dogs
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        My Pets
    </a>
</nav>
```